# CSS Sprites and Anchors

Tags: css, sprite

I would like to use some icons as links as well as have text links beneath each one but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it. So each icon and text links work.
Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huwrowlands/jvMfY/

Could some one show my the error of my ways.

Thanks in advance

```
<ul class="i-icons">            
 <li class="i-icon-va tablet-grid-33 mobile-grid-50"><a href="#">Vehicle Accidents</a></li>
 <li class="i-icon-pi tablet-grid-33 mobile-grid-50"><a href="#">Personal Injury</a></li>           
</ul>

#homepage-header ul.i-icons {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#homepage-header ul.i-icons li {
    /*text-indent: -9999em;*/
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    background-image: url('http://inspiredworx-labs.com/sites/injury-icons.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
}

    #homepage-header ul.i-icons li.i-icon-va {
        background-position: 0 -1px;
    }

    #homepage-header ul.i-icons li.i-icon-pi {
        background-position: -155px -1px;
    }   

#homepage-header ul.i-icons li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: can you clarify what you need? Are you saying you want the text to be underneath the icon and not on top? or something else? your question isnt clear

Comment: Apologies if my question is not clear. I want the text to be beneath.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jvMfY/2/)?

I simply added a `top` property to `#homepage-header ul.i-icons li a` and changed the font color so you can read it

**Update:** I changed the fiddle so that the text is underneath *and* the icons are clickable, however the text underneath is not clickable. Because you have styling for the list anchor tag, it was affecting the text, so the only option was to keep the text inside the `li` but outside the `a`. You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jvMfY/5/). If you want the text to be clickable, you might have to make a separate div to position underneath the list icons, there might be a better way but this was the best I could think of.

Comment: Almost got it. I came up with that too but the icon is not clickable doing it that way.

Comment: its 2am where i am i'll find a solution in the morning haha

Comment: Hi Sam. Your help has been great, thank you. I would like the text to be clickable also so I think I need to re-think my HTML and perhaps add a div or span in there somewhere. Or even just use real images instead of css sprite background-image ?

Comment: Yea I was going to suggest using regular images. Sprites are more useful when you want a hover affect such as changing the color of the image when you hover over it. check out this article by A List Apart on sprites: http://alistapart.com/article/sprites I always refer people to this tutorial because it's very detailed and walks you through every step to make it perfect. Anyway glad I could be of help and good luck!